# unit testing protected class methods in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

I am trying to import a class, than test a method (production_warning) from that class by passing in values 'stage', 'prod' to see if it returns the expected results.

```
import runner
test=runnerData(force_redeploy=False, pfactor=None, preview=True)

def production_warning_test():
    assert.test.production_warning('stage') not errors
    assert.test.production_warning('prod') contains "warning"

#run unit test
productionwarningtest()
```

I am clearly using assert completely wrong here, how do I properly accomplish what I'm trying to do with assert.

Comment: There are no such things as "protected class methods" in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with asserts, you'd want to change your assert statements to something like:

```
assert test.production_warning('stage') is not errors
assert test.production_warning('prod') contains "warning"
```

I'd highly recommend looking into the python [unit test](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) module instead though.

In which case you'd want something like this (note runnerData will need to be in scope, I'm just copying from your question above):

```
import runner
import unittest

class TestRunner(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
      self.test = runnerData(force_redeploy=False, pfactor=None, preview=True) 

  def test_production_warning(self):
      self.assertTrue(self.test.production_warning('stage') is not errors)
      self.assertTrue(self.test.production_warning('prod') contains "warning")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This is actually what I was going for, I am trying to use unittest, from reading the docs I can't figure out the cleanest way to do these two lines using unittest

Comment: I've expanded the answer to give an example using unittest - hopefully that should help.

Comment: Can I do this exact same thing, but without the class?

Comment: without TestRunner class?

Comment: Not with unittest - the various assertTrue etc. type functions provided by unittest are all methods of unittest.TestCase and expect self as their first argument. If you genuinely need to avoid using a class than you can go back to the plain asserts - you know your scenario best, so pick the best tool for the situation.